# How to host a reactJS application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, deployment

I am assuming I should be able to deploy my reactJS to an S3 instance on AWS but I do not know how to do this.  I found publish-react-app on github and I am trying to follow those steps.  When I execute npm run build I get this error stream:

```
c:\jrs\PM_01\React>npm run build
npm ERR! missing script: build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-05T18_57_19_811Z-debug.log

c:\jrs\PM_01\React>npm run build

> sample-app@1.0.0 build c:\jrs\PM_01\React
> react-scripts build

'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sample-app@1.0.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sample-app@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-05T19_06_24_048Z-debug.log
```

I have no idea what I need to put into the scrips section of my package.json file.  This is what my package.json file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "sample-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "ebay-node-api": "^2.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
    "publish-react-app": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-barcode": "^1.3.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-moment": "^0.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1",
    "simple-flexbox": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "es2015",
        {
          "modules": false
        }
      ],
      "stage-2",
      "react"
    ]
  }
}
```

I created a free tier S3 on AWS and created a user and a bucket but I really dont know what else to do in order to get my application deployed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `package.json` is missing the key `build`.  Generally with tools such as create-react-app it comes with a build script to prepare assets for production. As for hosting, Heroku is pretty easy to get up and running quickly.

Comment: but what would I put in?  Are there default values?  If so, what would they be?  Are there required values? If so, what would they be?

Comment: If you don't already have a build script for production I would not use that publish-react-app package unless you can customize it.  Most build scripts are more complex and deal with minifiying your javascript

Comment: Im not married to publish-react-app.  It's just something that I found and I thought it would help me deploy me react application.  But I still have no idea what to do next in order for me to deploy my app to the AWS service.  Or any other service for that matter.